# Same line Jade If Statement

Tags: node.js, conditional-statements, pug

I would like to be able to do an if statement on the same line in jade

```
 input(type='text', name='email', placeholder='Email', value='#{user.email}')
```

`user.email` should only display if it is defined.

```
 //For example:
 input(type='text', name='email', placeholder='Email', value='if user.email #{user.email}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [values of attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/) are JavaScript expressions, allowing you to reference variables without any additional syntax and is also why literal (string) values require quotes.

```
input(type='text', value=user.email)
```

If the value assigned to the attribute is `null` or `undefined`, Jade will already exclude it from the resulting markup:

```
- user = { email: null }
input(type='text', value=user.email)
```

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Life lesson. Read docs, thanks very much for your knowledge :)